# How to pass html/components to a blazor template?

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-blazor

Here is my case:

I have a component `Foo` and I want it to have a blazor template called `Wrapper` which will be used to wrap somepart of `Foo`'s content.

What I need to do is something like

Normal usage:

```
<Foo>
    <Wrapper>
        <div>
            <p>Something in the wraper</p>
            @context // context should be some content of Foo
        </div>
    </Wraper>
</Foo>
```

Inside `Foo`

```
@* Other content of Foo*@

@if(Wrapper != null){
    @* Pass to Wrapper some content of Foo *@
    Wrapper(@* How to render html/components here? *@)
}

@* Other content of Foo*@
```

But there is no way to pass html or components for the template?

How can I do this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question very well. Are you talking about ChildContent? (You may also be interested in Templated controls?)

Comment: I will try to elaborate more my question, but what is a templated control?

Comment: Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @ChananBraunstein the docs explain about `Templated Components`, which it different from `Templated controls`. Also, the docs don't have an example where you have a `RenderFragment<RenderFragment>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Wrapper in this case is a RenderFragment that you want to accept another RenderFragment, so it's signature would be

```
[Parameter] public RenderFragment<RenderFragment> Wrapper {get;set;}
```

Here is the complete Foo.razor

```
@* Other content of Foo*@
<h1>This is Foo</h1>

@if(Wrapper != null){
    @* Pass to Wrapper some content of Foo *@
    @Wrapper(
        @<h2>This comes from Foo</h2>
    )
}

<h1>There is no more Foo</h1>

@code 
{
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<RenderFragment> Wrapper {get;set;}
}
```

Notice carefully the construct inside the call to Wrapper.

1. Start with @Wrapper so this is a call from Razor
2. The open `(` after Wrapper puts you back in C# land, so -
3. use `@` to swap back to Razor code.
4. Now you can use Razor/HTML markup `<h2>This comes from Foo</h2>`
5. Close the call to `Wrapper` with a `)`

That is how you can use a RenderFragment that takes a RenderFragment as it's context.

The output from this would be

## This is Foo

Something in the wraper

### This comes from Foo

## There is no more Foo

You can test it out here https://blazorfiddle.com/s/ox4tl146

Comment: Fun thing to do: Format this code in vs2019 and see what happens

Comment: My guess is it adds empty comments?

Comment: Yep... also break everything